# Extracting data from an API call

Tags: node.js, request

Trying to extract data from an object that came back from an API call using **request**. 
When I try `info.featrues[0]` I get a **TypeError** 
When i use `info.features` i get **undefined**
But `res.body` works perfectly fine.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong
[image]

Comment: why don't you log just `info`?

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to be parsed. I added 'json: true to the request module. request({url: url, json:true}, (err, res)=>{};

Comment: When you log just info it isn't parsed. That's whats the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to be parsed. 
 Add `json: true` to the **request** module.
 `request({url: url, json:true}, (err, res)=>{};`